# Replace, VS 2010, regex

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2010, replace

I am trying to do the following mass replacements in VS 2010, using regular expressions :

string val_x = function(row[""].ToString());  into

string val_x = function(row["x"].ToString());

I built the finding expression as

string val_{.*}:b=:bfunction(row[\"\"].ToString())\;

The finding works fine.
But I am having no success at all with the replacement string...
I find online help rather obscure. Can anyone help?
THANKS!!!
Giuseppe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't actually used find/replace regex in Visual Studio before, but after having a quick poke around with the example you've provided above, I think you can achieve what you've after (although perhaps not in the easiest way), by breaking your original string into the following capture regions (I found I had to include some additional slashes to escape things):

```
|     \1     |\2 |           \3         |         \4        |
{string val_}{.*}{:b=:bfunction\(row\["}{"\].ToString\(\)\);}
```

And then for the replacement sections, using this:

`\1\2\3\2\4`

Edit: Forgot to mention, potentially helpful MSN source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs.aspx